# How to read with python, input from keyboard in the terminal, by calling the script.py through an alias

Tags: python, shell, alias

I essentially call a python script through an alias from the terminal:

```
 alias dos='python /path/to/script.py' .
```

This will run the python script.py in the current directory from where I launch it.

I would like to do something like that, from the terminal, for exaple:

```
dos 1 2
```

so that the code will read the input values 1 and 2, and be able to assign their values to some variables in the code.

How is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Whether or not you use an alias to launch the script makes no difference at all for your actual question. A better solution is simply to make the script executable, make sure it has a valid shebang, and save it in a directory which is on your `PATH`.

Comment: actually I am on mac, I don't know if it possible to do it like that. it is why I am using alias instead.